# Protege SWRL rules

Tags: semantics, semantic-web, owl, protege, rdfs

I've been trying to define rules in my ontology to infer that if a person has friends who are friends amongst each other then all are friends, but if 1 or more are not friends to each other then my ontology will infer that they all, are not friends.

[image: my diagram]

Thank you

Comment: Your `isFriendWith(?y)` is missing a second variable if it wants to be a relation.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to get your intended semantics straightened out a little bit more.

From what I gather, you want `isFriendWith` at least to be symmetric, i.e. when `isFriendWith(bob, alice)` then also `isFriendWith(alice, bob)`.

Also, if you want to have `friendsAll` to have any meaning, `isFriendWith` cannot be transitive. This would also capture the *natural* meaning, as a friend of my friend is not necessarily my friend.

To elaborate: If `isFriendWith` where *symmetric* and *transitive* every friend of `bob` would automatically also be a friend of all of bob's friends (because `isFriendWith(bob, alice)` implies `isFriendWith(alice, bob)`. From there on, with any `isFriendWith(bob, carol)` transitivity implies that `isFriendWith(alice, carol)`. So if `isFriendWith` is symmetric and transitive, you get the clique automatically.

But as stated, this is probably not, what you want.

As for formulating this in *SWRL*, let's give it a try, shall we?

`friendsAll` is most likely *reflexive*, i.e. let's just assume everybody is his/her own friend. Now, we need an recursive rule that extends this set while still fulfilling the condition: "*In this set, everybody is everybody's friend*".

To include bob's friends, you would need to be able to quantify over `isFriendWith` and check if that any *candidate friend* of `bob` is also a friend of *all* other friends of `bob`. Since you cannot nest quantifiers in SWRL, I'm more or less sure, you cannot express that algorithm in the rule language alone. However, I maybe wrong here and there is a neat little trick hidden inside the semantics. It is not one that I know of, however and the need for quantifier nesting in the direct formulation leaves me believing that it is not possible.

It basically boils down to a well-known graph-theoretic problem: given a starting point `bob` `friendsAll` is the largest subset of `bob`'s friends such that every everbody in the group is friends with everyone else, i.e. bob's Maximal [Clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem).

Comment: Very instructive. Would you add information about "cannot be transitive"? What might the second variable be? Also, would you elaborate on O(N2) v. a SWIRL rule. I believe you are saying that SWIRL cannot solve a cliques of fixed size. Would you explain why?

Comment: As I said, your question does not even get the syntax right, so I'd suggest more research wrt. OWL/DL and SWRL Rules.

Comment: I didn't ask the SO question. I was reading your useful response and asking for clarification. TY for updated response.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't read the username. Also see edited answer.

Comment: @dhke Thank you for your great response! Sorry I've not specified very clear my rules, I've defined that property to be symmetric. Transitive could be the solution but I cannot assume that Bob and Carol are friends because of Alice. And as you said there is a Clique problem!!. Could you please help me with this other issue? I have to add a description to this relationships. For example, A isFriendWith B -> "they were students in St Vicent" I want to assign one or more descriptions to this relationship. Do I have to define  another IRI or blank node, one that represents the relationship?.

Comment: @user3591709: I think the latter warrants another SO question. What you want is to assign properties to a relation triple. That is only possible in RDF (via *reification*) not in OWL/DL and should be avoided if possible. If you really need the information, you probably need an intermediate `Friendship` object, much like an intermediate table in a relational database